# Increase the size lvm2 partition to use all unallocated disk space

Tags: partition, volume

I have imaged a smaller drive to a larger drive.  I now need to increase the size of the parition/volume group (correct term?).  The drive has ~1.6 TiB of unallocated space which I want /dev/sdb3 to use then allocate that increase to /dev/cl/root.  Below is some information cobbled together from google searching.  The first four pieces are from gparted.

```
/dev/sdb1    fat16        /boot/efi  200 MiB
/dev/sdb2    ext4         /boot      1.0 GiB
/dev/sdb3    lvm2 pv      cl      221.68 GiG
unallocated  unallocated            1.60 TiB

$ sudo lvmdiskscan

  /dev/sdb1       [     200.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sdb2       [       1.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sdb3       [     221.68 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/cl/var     [     100.00 GiB] 
  /dev/cl/swap    [       2.00 GiB] 
  /dev/cl/root    [     110.00 GiB] 


$ sudo lsblk
    NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sdb               8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
    ├─sdb2            8:18   0     1G  0 part 
    ├─sdb3            8:19   0 221.7G  0 part 
    │ ├─cl-swap     253:1    0     2G  0 lvm  
    │ ├─cl-root     253:2    0   110G  0 lvm  
    │ └─cl-var      253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  
    └─sdb1            8:17   0   200M  0 part 


$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb3
  VG Name               cl
  PV Size               221.68 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              56749
  Free PE               2478
  Allocated PE          54271
  PV UUID               Uohq5b-Ubkr-f51E-y1tf-vfAi-JA06-dKWx7A
```

I tried to increase physical size by using `sudo pvresize /dev/sdb3` with the output of

```
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Though this didn't seem to do anything.  I can't resize /dev/sdb3 within gparted.  I tried to increase the volume group using

```
$ sudo vgextend cl /dev/sdb3
  Can't open /dev/sdb3 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

I am not sure why it failed as I don't think /dev/sdb3 is mounted as the physical drive is attached to within another Linux CentOS 7 system which was used to image the hard drive.

How can I resize/extend `/dev/sdb3` to use the reset of the unallocated space then increase /sdb3/cl-root to use all of the new space?

Some response I have seen show creating a new partition within the unallocated space and then adding it to the group/volume, but I was hoping to increase /dev/sdb3 to use the remaining unallocated space then increase the size of /sdb3/cl-root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll have to edit the partition table to actually extend the `sdb3` partition. You might use `gparted`, `parted`, `gdisk` or `fdisk` for this.

If you use `gdisk` or `fdisk`, the changes are only written to the partition table when you tell the program to do it, so with a single `gdisk`/`fdisk` session, you can view the exact disk location (block/sector number) where `sdb3` begins, *delete* the `sdb3` partition, *recreate* it with **the exact same starting point** and a new end point, and then write the updated partition table to the disk.

If the kernel does not accept the new partition size immediately, you might have to run `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` at this point.

Once the new partition size is visible in `/proc/partitions`, you can proceed with `sudo pvresize /dev/sdb3` exactly as you did. After that, `sudo pvdisplay` should indicate increased `PV size`, `Total PE` and `Free PE` values.

At that point, you can use `sudo lvextend -r -L <desired new size> /dev/cl/root` to extend your LV.

Since `sdb3` PV is already a member of the `cl` volume group, you don't need `vgextend` in this case: it is only used when you're adding a new, unused PV into an existing volume group. Since the VG is currently active and all its LVs are mounted/in use, the PV is locked for exclusive access by the LVM, so even the `vgextend` tool cannot access it directly. If you tried to do the `vgextend` by booting from an external media, so that the LVs would be unmounted, you would see an error message

```
Physical volume '/dev/sdb3' is already in volume group 'cl'
```

instead.

Comment: "block/sector number) where sdb3 begins, delete the sdb3 partition, recreate it with the exact same starting point and a new end point, and then write the updated partition table to the disk." -- If I delete the sdb3 partition and recreate it, will the data be gone?  I would like to keep the data if possible.  If this process does not keep the data I should be able to copy the partition from the original disk to the new disk I would image.

Comment: Linux ` fdisk`/` gdisk`  will only update the partition table and nothing else. So if you overwrite the partition table with one that specifies the same beginning position and a new ending position for an existing partition, that is how a partition gets extended without any change to its actual contents. But ` gparted`  and `parted`  have a "resize partition" function that does exactly the same thing, but they have the advantage that with that function you *cannot* even accidentally change the starting point of the partition.